# How to aggregate/ sum values by time in r

Tags: r, data-cleaning

There are 2 issues:

1. I have time data in factor format and I want to change it into date format for later manipulation.
2. The goal is to sum values of precipitation of the same time unit, eg. precipitation per hour.

I tried to convert the time using `as.POSIXct()` or `as.date()` in `lubridate` but always get `NA` values after defining the format. This is the code I used:

```
tt=as.POSIXct(FixUseNew$StartTimestamp, )
df$time <- as.Date(df$time, "%d-%m-%Y")

If I leave out the format and do the following : 
tt=as.POSIXct(df$time)

tt 

hour(tt)
```

The date data looks like this now: `"0010-07-14 00:38:00 LMT"`

I wanted to use `aggregate` function to sum the precipitation in the same hour interval or day but couldn't do it as I am stuck with the date format.

Just a brain dump. I was going to change the factor date in to character then to date format as following. Please advise if that is a good idea.

```
df$time <-paste(substr(df$time,6,7),
                              substr(df$time,9,10), 
                              substr(df$time,1,4),sep="/")
```

Here is a subset of the data, hope this helps to illustrate the question better:

```
Id <- c(1,2,3,4)
Time <- c("10/7/2014  12:30:00 am", "10/7/2014  01:00:05 am","10/7/2014  01:30:10 am", "10/7/2014  02:00:15 am")
Precipitation <- c(0.06, 0.02,0,0.25)
cbind(Id, Time, Precipitation)
```

Thank you so much.

Here is the outcome:
It seems like the order is distorted:

```
6      1/1/15 0:35         602
7      1/1/15 0:36         582
8      1/1/15 0:37         958
9      1/1/15 0:38         872
10    1/10/14 0:31         500
11    1/10/14 0:32         571
12    1/10/14 0:33         487
13    1/10/14 0:34         220
14    1/10/14 0:35         550
15    1/10/14 0:36         582
16    1/10/14 0:37         524
17    1/10/14 0:38         487

           ⋮

106 10/10/14 15:16         494
107  10/10/14 7:53          37
108  10/10/14 7:56          24
109  10/10/14 8:01           3
110  10/11/14 0:30         686
111  10/11/14 0:31         592
112  10/11/14 0:32         368
113  10/11/14 0:33         702
114  10/11/14 0:34         540
115  10/11/14 0:35         564
```

Comment: Please add a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Hi Ronak, "0010-07-14" refers to 10/7/2014  12:30:00 am.

Comment: `format="%m/%d/%Y"`? I suggest you read `?strptime` and `?as.POSIXct`.

Comment: Thank you for the reminder. I have changed the data.

Comment: @JamesMartherus I have attached a  minimal reproducible example. Thanks for the reminder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `dplyr` and `lubridate` packages we can extract the `hour` from each `Time` and `sum`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>%
  mutate(hour = hour(dmy_hms(Time))) %>%
  group_by(hour) %>%
  summarise(Precipitation = sum(Precipitation, na.rm = TRUE))
```

For aggregation by date, we can do

```
df %>%
  mutate(day = as.Date(dmy_hms(Time))) %>%
  group_by(day) %>%
  summarise(Precipitation = sum(Precipitation, na.rm = TRUE))
```

---

Using base R, we could do

```
df$Hour <- format(as.POSIXct(df$Time, format = "%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S %p"), "%H")
df$Day <- as.Date(as.POSIXct(df$Time, format = "%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S %p"))

#Aggregation by hour
aggregate(Precipitation~Hour, df, sum, na.rm = TRUE)

#Aggregation by date
aggregate(Precipitation~Day, df, sum, na.rm = TRUE)
```

**EDIT**

Based on updated data and information, we can do

```
df <- readxl::read_xlsx("/path/to/file/df (1).xlsx")

hour_df <- df %>%
             group_by(hour = hour(Time)) %>%
             summarise(Precipitation = sum(Precipitation, na.rm = TRUE))


day_df <-  df %>%
              mutate(day = as.Date(Time)) %>%
              group_by(day) %>%
              summarise(Precipitation = sum(Precipitation, na.rm = TRUE))
```

So `hour_df` has got hourly `sum` of values without taking into consideration the date and `day_df` has got `sum` of `Precipitation` for each day.

**data**

```
Id <- c(1,2,3,4)
Time <- c("10/7/2014  12:30:00 am", "10/7/2014  01:00:05 am",
          "10/7/2014  01:30:10 am", "10/7/2014  02:00:15 am")
Precipitation <- c(0.06, 0.02,0,0.25)
df <- data.frame(Id, Time, Precipitation)
```

Comment: Ronak thank you so much for the answer. I forgot to mention that the data spread over 1 year period. When I group by hour or day, the outcome disregards the day or month. Is it possible to fix that issue? Thanks

Comment: @Harper Do you mean you want to group all the hours together for the entire dataset? So `10/7/2014  12:30:00 am` and `11/7/2014  12:30:00 am` would come in the same group?

Comment: Here is the outcome(sorry about the messy format): 6      1/1/15 0:35         602
7      1/1/15 0:36         582
8      1/1/15 0:37         958
9      1/1/15 0:38         872
10    1/10/14 0:31         500
11    1/10/14 0:32         571
12    1/10/14 0:33         487
13    1/10/14 0:34         220
14    1/10/14 0:35         550
15    1/10/14 0:36         582
16    1/10/14 0:37         524
17    1/10/14 0:38         487

Comment: I want to group all the hours regardless of date(so 10/7/2014 12:30:00 am and 11/7/2014 12:30:00 am would come in the same group)  to observe the 24-hour pattern. I also want to group daily precipitation by taking consideration of date to observe the trend over time,(ie. I'll get individual daily data for 10/7/2014, 11/7/2014,11/7/2014 by summing up all precipitation in one day). However, my outcome looks like the order of data is distorted. Please check the original question for the output. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Harper Honestly, I am pretty confused about your data. You first said you had data like `"0010-07-14 00:38:00 LMT"`, then you updated your post with data like `"10/7/2014  12:30:00 am"` and now you have again updated post with data like `1/1/15 0:35`. All 3 of them are completely different format and require different way to handle them. I don't know which one is correct format and represent your original data. It is very important to share the data in their real format hence I asked you to share it using `dput`. The answers posted might not work if you share incorrect information.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, "10/7/2014 12:30:00 am" is the original data format in excel; "0010-07-14 00:38:00 LMT" is the console output after applying tt=as.POSIXct(df$time) to the data. 1/1/15 0:35 is the console output after doing aggregation by date. I will try to upload the data using dput. Thanks

Comment: @Harper don't do any changes in the data. Import the data in R and keep the data in excel format only which is `"10/7/2014 12:30:00 am"`. You can use the above answer after that and see if it works for you.

Comment: # A tibble: 1 x 2
  day        Activations
  <date>           <int>
1 NA             1288992
Warning message:
All formats failed to parse. No formats found.  I did as you advised but an error occurred

Comment: can you share `dput(head(df))`  and `dput(head(FixUseNew))` ?

Comment: Is it possible that I send you the data file through email? I couldn't do it on here. Many thanks

Comment: Here is the dput outcome. The time in excel looks like 30:01.1 format, but upon clicking on the cell it looks like "10/7/2014  12:30:01 am". > dput(head(FixUseNew))
structure(list(Id = 86417:86422, Time = structure(3:8, .Label = c("27/7/14 0:37", 
"27/7/14 0:38", "31:14.1", "31:14.4", "31:16.1", "31:16.5", "31:16.8", 
...
"33:06.4", "33:08.1", "33:08.5", "33:08.9", "33:09.2", "33:11.0", 
"33:11.4", "33:11.7", "33:12.1"), class = "factor"), Precipitation = c(2L, 
7L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 12L)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: @Harper based on your `dput` your `Time` column has `31:14.1` What is that supposed to mean?

Comment: I am not sure what that means. Is it valid if we change it to d/mm/yyyy h:mm in Excel before working on it using R? We can change the date to "10/07/2014 0:30" format in Excel.

Comment: @Harper Can you check the **EDIT** of the answer and see if it works for you now? It worked for me on the sample you provided.

Comment: The codes work for me! I notice that many cases accumulated in a particular hour because it disregards the dates. Is it possible to group them by both date and hour? Thanks

Comment: @Harper you just need to combine both of them then `df %>%
             group_by(hour = hour(Time), day = as.Date(Time)) %>%
             summarise(Precipitation = sum(Precipitation, na.rm = TRUE))`